# Deploy config for a WLAN via group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, wifi

Ok, So what I would like to do is to deploy a preconfigured WLAN with key so everyone automaticly connects to the right network if they unplug their network cable.

We have 2 WLAN:s at the office

COMPANY-OFFICE & COMPANY-GUEST.
The one i want to deploy is COMPANY-OFFICE.

I found the wlan config group policy but it does not allow me to set the password for the access point, any ideas how to do that?

I've seen some solutions with scripts but never got them to work. 
So all help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you already found it. GPO does not support WLAN configuration with Passwords. That would be a pretty bad security hole since anyone in your company could just read the password out of the GPO and use it for anything they like, including telling people who shouldn't know, writing it down on a sticky note, etc.

What you'll want to do is setup WPA or WPA2 with certificates (not PreShared Keys, aka Passwords). This can be configured completely from GPO. You'll need to configure 802.1X on the WAPs and a [Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771455%28WS.10%29.aspx). The setup process isn't terrible quick or easy, but it just runs after you've got it setup once.